For infinite cardinals $\kappa$, we have $\kappa \otimes \kappa = \kappa$.
I am aware that other questions are quite similar to this; however, it seems like the other questions regarding the same statement are looking at proofs that seem somewhat different from the one I am interested in, so here goes:
On page $29$ in Kunen's "Set Theory Introduction to Independence Proofs", he wants to prove that for infinite cardinals $\kappa$, we have $\kappa \otimes \kappa = \kappa$.
I'll provide the proof in full (paraphrased):

We prove this by transfinite induction on $\kappa$. Assume this holds for smaller cardinals. Then for $\alpha < \kappa$, we have
\begin{align*}
\alpha \otimes \alpha &= |\alpha \times \alpha|\\
&= |\alpha| \otimes |\alpha|\\
&< \kappa
\end{align*}
(applying lemma 10.10 when $\alpha$ is finite, which says that for $m,n \in \omega: m \otimes n < \omega$). Define a well-ordering $\triangleleft$ on $\kappa \times \kappa$ by
$$
\langle \alpha,\beta \rangle \ \triangleleft \ \langle \gamma,\delta \rangle \iff \text{max}(\alpha,\beta) < \text{max}(\gamma,\delta) \lor \left[\text{max}(\alpha,\beta) = \text{max}(\gamma,\delta) \land \langle \alpha,\beta \rangle \ \text{precedes} \ \langle \gamma,\delta \rangle \ \text{lexicographically}\right].
$$
Each $\langle \alpha,\beta \rangle \in \kappa \times \kappa$ has no more than $|(\text{max}(\alpha,\beta)+1) \times (\text{max}(\alpha,\beta)+1)| < \kappa$ predecessors in $\triangleleft$, so $\text{type}(\kappa \times \kappa, \triangleleft) \leq \kappa$, whence $|\kappa \times \kappa| \leq \kappa$. Since clearly $|\kappa \times \kappa| \geq |\kappa| = \kappa$, we have
$$
|\kappa \times \kappa| = |\kappa| = \kappa.$$

Now, I am having a really hard time trying to understand even the structure of this proof. For example, as a friend pointed out, why is he taking account of finite cardinals $\alpha$ in the proof? Is it because the induction is really on showing that for all $\alpha < \kappa$ we have $|\alpha \times \alpha| \leq \kappa$, and the induction is not on the property $\kappa \otimes \kappa = \kappa$. The first induction makes sense since if he was really doing induction on $\kappa \otimes \kappa = \kappa$ for infinite cardinals, the base case would be $\omega$ (and we could disregard finite $\alpha$). I have looked at this proof for quite a while but I am still having trouble understanding the logical structure of the proof.
I would appreciate anyone who could elucidate this clearly for me.

Among other reasons, he's accounting for finite cardinals in order to apply the proof to $\aleph_0 \otimes \aleph_0$.
The structure of the proof is just that for any $\alpha \lt \kappa$, we know by the induction hypothesis that $\vert \alpha \times \alpha \vert \lt \kappa$.  Using this knowledge, we create a well ordering of $\kappa \times \kappa$ such that any ordered pair $(\alpha, \beta) \in \kappa \times \kappa$ has fewer than $\kappa$ predecessors.  That well order tells us that $\vert \kappa \times \kappa \vert \leq \kappa$.

Thanks for your input, hmm, can you please expand a little on the point $\aleph_{0} \otimes \aleph_0$? I suppose you mean that we need to show that it holds for the base case $\aleph_0 = \omega$. But why is this needed, do we not know that $\omega \otimes \omega = |\omega+\omega| = |\omega| = \omega < \kappa$ assuming $\omega < \kappa$. Or oh, perhaps you mean in the case that $\kappa = \omega$. Right.
I would be really happy if you can elucidate why $(\alpha,\beta) \in \kappa \times \kappa$ having fewer than $\kappa$ predecessors implies $|\kappa \times \kappa| \leq \kappa$.

If all initial segments of a well ordering have order type strictly less than $\kappa$, then the entire well ordering must have order type no greater than $\kappa$.  If the well ordering had order type $\kappa + 1$ (or anything greater), then it would have an initial segment with order type $\kappa$.

Don’t you want to use the inductive assumption on $\text{max}(\alpha,\beta) + 1$? That does not work if you only do transfinite induction over cardinals. So I assume that the induction is over all ordinals  $\alpha < \kappa$. Otherwise I don’t see how we know that $|(\text{max}(\alpha,\beta) + 1) \times (\text{max}(\alpha,\beta) + 1)| < \kappa$.
That is, we know that $\text{max}(\alpha,\beta) + 1$ is not a limit ordinal. In fact, it is a successor-ordinal. So we need to do the induction over ordinals less than $\kappa$, I think.

@Ben123 If you already know that $\alpha \otimes \alpha =\vert \alpha \times \alpha \vert = \vert \alpha \vert \otimes \vert \alpha \vert$, then you have what you need.

I don't agree that we know this for $\alpha$ that are ordinals unless we do the induction over all ordinals less than $\kappa$. If you restrict the induction to cardinals, then how exactly do you know that $|(\text{max}(\alpha,\beta) +1) \times (\text{max}(\alpha,\beta)+1)| < \kappa$? Nothing hinders $\alpha > \beta > \omega$ and the $\alpha$ is an infinite ordinal, so that $\alpha+1$ is an infinite successor-ordinal, so not a cardinal. And then we can't use the inductive assumption. Why am I wrong?
Or is there some other property you can use in these cases?

Sorry, can't edit, what I mean is; nothing hinders $\alpha$ being an infinite ordinal greater than some other ordinal $\beta$, both in $\kappa$. But then $\text{max}(\alpha,\beta)+1 = \alpha+1$, which is an infinite successor-ordinal (so not a limit-ordinal, hence not an infinite cardinal).

@Ben123 But since $\alpha, \beta \lt \kappa$, each has cardinality less than $\kappa$.  I think that observation gets you where you need to be.

I am not sure I follow.

Also, I am not sure you can prove the statement "If all initial segments of a well-ordering are less than $\kappa$, then the well-ordering itself is less than $\kappa$" without using the theorem we are trying to prove. I think I have only seen this proved in a way where one uses the theorem $\kappa \cdot \kappa = \kappa$.

See here for a discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89984/cardinality-of-a-some-linear-ordering-is-at-most-that-of-a-given-cardinal/90000#90000

@Ben123 If an ordinal $\alpha$ has cardinality $\lambda \gt \kappa$, then $\kappa$ is an initial segment of $\lambda$ so $\alpha$ has a proper initial segment of order type $\kappa$, contrary to assumption.

Sorry, I don't see the relevance to what we are discussing?

I mean, there is a relevance in the proof, as formulated in ... (sorry, can't find the link now).
But I don't see the relevance for what I wrote about your statement "If all initial segments of a well-ordering...".

@Ben123 Kunen explicitly constructs a well ordering of $\kappa \times \kappa$ that satisfies this condition.  The definition of a cardinal is an ordinal that cannot be placed in $1$-$1$ correspondence with any smaller ordinal, and you (presumably) already know that any two ordinals, and therefore any two cardinals, are comparable.  So if $\kappa \times \kappa$ had cardinality $\lambda \gt \kappa$, then there is an order-preserving isomorphism between the constructed well order and some ordinal $\beta \geq \lambda$.  Some initial segment of $\kappa \times \kappa$ would have order type $\kappa$.
